# Passing variables get undefined after 'Refreshing the page' in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to passing values from one page to another page...In a page seller-profile.php, when i refresh the page all passing data from seller-ride.php gets undefined, so i have to get back to the seller-ride then click on button then all data get display, How can i avoid this kind of situation? please suggest me better solution!

**seller-ride.php**

```
<form method="post" action="seller-profile.php">
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['company_name']; ?>" name="c_name" readonly>  </td>
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['mobile']; ?>" name="mob" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['count_free']; ?>" name="cf" readonly></td>
    <td> <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['count_travel']; ?>" name="ct" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" name="p" readonly>
    <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-flat btn-primary btn-sm" value="View-Profile" name="submit"></button></td>
</form>
```

**seller-profile.php**

```
<?php
include 'seller-profile-config.php';
?>
<?php echo $company_name; ?>
<?php echo $mobile; ?>
<?php echo $count_free; ?>
<?php echo $count_travel; ?>
<?php echo $price; ?>
```

**seller-profile-config.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$company_name=$_POST['c_name'];
$mobile=$_POST['mob'];
$total_income=$_POST['p'];
$count_free=$_POST['cf'];
$count_travel=$_POST['ct'];

}
?>
```

Comment: That's how POST behave. You have to handle in your code. Either store the values in session/cookies (if most needed) otherwise prevent direct access to this page or prevent refresh

Comment: @Thamilan Can you please elaborate both things with examples?